# Binary representation of NSString

Tags: nsstring, nsdata

I need to someone to send me binary data via NSStream and I will convert it into NSString on my end.  What's the binary representation that they need to know (byte size, byte order) in order for me to convert the data successfully back into the same string in NSString?

Answer (score 1):

First get the data and convert it into `NSData`
Then convert `NSData` to `NSString`

```
NSString* newStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

If the data is null-terminated, you should instead use -stringWithUTF8String: to avoid the extra \0 at the end.

```
NSString* newStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[theData bytes]];
```

(If you have ARC enabled, remove the -autorelease call.)